# How to Configure AWS Transfer Family to Invoke Specific Lambda Functions Based on S3 Bucket, Without Using an Intermediary Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-transfer-family

I'm facing a challenge with the configuration of the AWS Transfer Family. I have multiple Lambda functions (such as b1 and b2) and would like each one to be invoked based on the specific S3 bucket where a file was received. The goal is to do this purely at the configuration level, without using an intermediary Lambda function.

I attempted to set up specific invocations of Lambda functions based on the S3 bucket within the AWS Transfer Family, using IAM policies or workflow configurations. I was expecting to find a straightforward way to direct the AWS Transfer Family to invoke a specific Lambda function (e.g., 'b1' or 'b2') based on the particular S3 bucket where the file was received. My aim was to achieve this purely at the configuration level, without the need for additional coding or intermediary Lambda functions.